# How can I select into a temporary variable mid sql statement

Tags: postgresql

I have following sql statement:

```
select * from funds_balance where account_id = 7 and sequence_number <= (
   select sequence_number from funds_balance where account_id = 7 and update_settlement_pool_id = 7
   union all
   select sequence_number from funds_balance_history where account_id = 7 and update_settlement_pool_id = 7
   limit 1
)
union all
select account_id, deliverable_id, cash, credit,pending,sequence_number, update_time,update_reason, update_funds_action_id, update_trade_serial, update_settlement_pool_id
from funds_balance_history where account_id = 7 and sequence_number <= (
   select sequence_number from funds_balance where account_id = 7 and update_settlement_pool_id = 7
   union all
   select sequence_number from funds_balance_history where account_id = 7 and update_settlement_pool_id = 7
   limit 1
)
order by sequence_number desc limit 2
```

In the above complex statement there are two identical sub-queries which I assume are executing twice.

Is there any way to only execute this sub-query once, maybe storing it some kind of temp variable to reference in the outer query?

Pseudo code below describing what I mean:

```
var seq_num = select sequence_number from funds_balance where account_id = 7 and update_settlement_pool_id = 7
   union all
   select sequence_number from funds_balance_history where account_id = 7 and update_settlement_pool_id = 7
   limit 1

select * from funds_balance where account_id = 7 and sequence_number <= seq_num
union all
select account_id, deliverable_id, cash, credit,pending,sequence_number, update_time,update_reason, update_funds_action_id, update_trade_serial, update_settlement_pool_id
from funds_balance_history where account_id = 7 and sequence_number <= seq_num
order by sequence_number desc limit 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply translate your expected behaviour into a SQL query, you can use [CTEs (`WITH` clauses)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) for that:

```
WITH seq_num AS (

   select sequence_number from funds_balance where account_id = 7 and update_settlement_pool_id = 7
   union all
   select sequence_number from funds_balance_history where account_id = 7 and update_settlement_pool_id = 7
   limit 1

)

select * from funds_balance where account_id = 7 
    and sequence_number <= (SELECT sequence_number FROM seq_num)
union all
select account_id, deliverable_id, cash, credit,pending,sequence_number, update_time,update_reason, update_funds_action_id, update_trade_serial, update_settlement_pool_id
from funds_balance_history where account_id = 7 
    and sequence_number <= (SELECT sequence_number FROM seq_num)
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking the sub-query I had was executing twice? Or does the query optimiser see it?

Comment: I believe that depends on your database config and table structure. Tbh, I am not quite sure, but you can see it when you display the execution plan: EXPLAIN ANALYZE <your query>.

Comment: EXPLAIN ANALYSE showed a 50% reduction in both planning time and execution time with your method.